# How to connect one audio system via a wired connection and another with bluetooth simultaneously?

Tags: audio, sync, bluetooth

Currently I have one laptop connecting to an audio speaker system via an audio output wire. I have another audio output system (a portable Bose) which can be connected via bluetooth of the laptop. Is there a way to simultaneously connecting and syncing the audio output to the two output systems, one via wire connection and another bluetooth connection?

Edited: My OS is windows 10.

Comment: Please add an OS tag. Under Linux, you can do that with Pulseaudio (though syncing by adding delays will be a bit of a hassle).

Comment: You could do it on Mac with Audio Hijack, including the delays. I know of nothing for Windows.

Comment: for Windows, there is Voicemeeter to do that. you can even use VBAN feature to send audio to mobile devices (with a better latency than bluetooth).

Comment: I installed voicemeeter and follow this tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpvae_2WOSQ&t=473s. I set A1 as "realtek HD audio" and A2 as "bose mini", even though when sound is played both the bars on the hardware out have the same ups and downs, the bose is not producing any sound.

Comment: Never mind, VoiceMeeter works after a bit of tinkering of settings. Thanks.